# Call sql script from another script in CLP

Tags: db2, clp

I'm using DB2 on Unix and I want to call a master script that run some other scripts within it. Note that I 'm using CLP.

The master script would like as follow in Oracle :

@@script1
@@script2
etc

Is it possible to achieve this in DB2 using CLP  ?

Note that I don't want to a bash script to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic CLP on Db2-LUW, accessed via the `db2` command, does not support that functionality.

If you do not want to use operating system scripting (such as bash etc) then your options are limited to the `!` operator in the classic CLP but it will only invoke a separate process (i.e command-line interface, no shared variables, no control etc).

However, the alternative `clpplus` tool ( a java app, that is present both in the Db2-server product, and some Db2-client products ) does support Oracle-style scripting  including the `@` and `@@` commands .